# How to style bootstrap 4 elements?

Tags: html, css, hover, bootstrap-4

I have a screenshot as show below which I have replicated in Bootstrap 4.

In the screenshot, on row hover the **background-color: #EDEDED;** shows up.

[image]

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1v8j05y/1/embedded/result/) for the above screenshot.

The HTML code which I have used in order to create the table is :

```
<div class="body-manage-attendees">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Number</th>
                <th scope="col">Table</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Amanda Doe</th>
                <td>250</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Bill</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Andy Doe</th>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Bill</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Cameron Doe</th>
                <td>250</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>No Bill</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Dana Doe</th>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Bill</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Fred Doe</th>
                <td>250</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Bill</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what I need to add in the CSS so that on row hover, the **background-color: #EDEDED;** appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap 3 class appears to still work. Try adding the hover class to your table.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
```

By doing so, this CSS class from bootstrap is applied:

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}
```

Feel free to override that class and change the color to whatever you wish!

Comment: Thanks for your code. I am wondering if you can update in the fiddle I have provided ?

Answer (score 1):

Add **.table-hover** class to your table:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
```

Alterinatively you an also use CSS:

```
table.table tr:hover td, table.table tr:hover th {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
}
```

Edit: [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/orewgswg/)